# Как по истечении определенного времени добавлять запись в Базу Данных?

Tags: php, mysqli

Как по истечении определенного времени добавлять запись в Базу Данных? Покажите на любом примере пожалуйста.

Comment: В чём задача, собстбвенно? Для чего это надо делать?

Comment: @InDevX, у меня в БД хранится время в формате varchar, и мне нужно, чтобы код сверял время на компьютере и в базе, и когда время на компьютере станет больше, чем в базе, в другую таблицу добавлялась запись о том, что время просрочено.

Comment: Самое сложное, конечно, в компьютерной науке - это объяснить принцип работы базы данных человеку, который не знает других средств хранения информации кроме тетради в клеточку.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Хм, кажется вы возомнили себя гением программирования. Но, понимаю вас, когда в коем-то веке встречаешь того, кто чуть менее вас знает предмет, хочется самоутвердиться, но попрошу вас сдерживаться)

Comment: @Зари Время в varchar это сильно (не надо так). Время на компютере - это вам на фронт, на беке надо с серваком сравнивать. И зачем запись в другой таблице? Сдаётся мне, Вам надо архитекруту приложения поправить, а не дальше костылями закидывать дыры. Время можно тем же кроном чекать, но опять таки - зачем метка о "просроченном" времени если можно просто его сравнивать с текущей датой?

Comment: Я думаю вы здесь не задержитесь

Comment: @Ипатьев, успехов ;)

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо большое, исправлю)

Answer (score 0):

Это не надо делать. Надо сразу сделать запись в БД, и в ней указать нужное время

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы это делалось автоматически в коде

Comment: Тогда этого вообще не надо делать.

Comment: Не нужно никакой второй таблицы и никакого автоматического добавления. База данных работает не так. Как я уже сказал, время берется из первой таблицы и проверяется.